# Automatically Change Select to Select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I need to dynamically add select box at several forms.

And to add the select box, I used different event name, because each form has different markup.
For example, to add new row on a table I used event named 'add-table-row', and to add new list item on a list I used event named 'add-list-item'.
(Better technique suggestion is very appreciated)

In each event function I have duplicate code to change select to select2. I have 2 type of select2 class.

`<select class="select2">` -> Normal Select2

`<select class="select2-minimum-input">` -> Select2 with minimumInputLength

So, my javascript code ended up with a lot of .select2() function call.

I want to reduce this kind of code duplication. Is there any better javascript technique to handle this? or I should keep this code style?

Answer (score 0):

you can write **function** which changes select to select2 and add it to every event you need. I think this is easiest way to reduce code duplication